# Scala StringBuilder

Tags: scala, stringbuilder, implicit-conversion

Is there an implicit method to convert scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder to java.lang.StringBuilder?

I am using a Java library (JCommander) in which one of the methods (`usage`) takes a `java.jang.StringBuilder` argument.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't *start* with a Scala `StringBuilder` and then obtain the Java version.  You can, however, wrap a `java.lang.StringBuilder` in the Scala version.  So:

```
val jsb = new java.lang.StringBuilder();
val sb = new StringBuilder(jsb);
// Do Scala-y stuff with sb
JCommander.whatever.usage(jsb);
// Do more Scala-y stuff
```

Since--not a guarantee, but true in practice right now (2.8, 2.9)--the Scala wrapper doesn't store any state (instead just referring to the Java version), you're safe to mix and match usage of the two.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the source code, it seems there's absolutely no way to get a `java.lang.StringBuilder` from a `scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder`.

You can create a new `java.lang.StringBuilder` with Scala's, going through a conversion of some type (`String` or `CharSequence`).

Answer (score 1):

Use this implicit transform do do this:

```
    implicit def b2b(b: scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder) = 
        new java.lang.StringBuilder(b)
```

Comment: Actually, I don't think that will work. I presume that any Java method that expects a `java.lang.StringBuilder` expects to modify it and allow the caller access to those changes. The `implicit` method you show creates a "defensive" copy of the `scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder`. Any changes in the called method will **not** be reflected in the `scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder`. Now that I think about it, the only way it could be implemented is if `scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder` extended or wrapped `java.lang.StringBuilder`.